# no module named pygame.base on lego ev3dev

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame, lego-mindstorms-ev3

On my Lego ev3 robot my current project is to add the pygame joystick module into my robot and get it up working so I can use my PS1 remote to control Lego ev3 robot. I have put the WHOLE folder from site-packages in python onto my robot and I am not getting the error `no module named pygame` but I am getting the error `no module named pygame.base` and many others like `no module named pygame.constants` after it.

I have looked at the robot's logfile which shows the errors that the code might have on a file that comes whenever you run the robot. I have tried running the robots python file via my computer and I have also tried it via the robot itself both lead to the same error.

I have tried running the same pygame on my computer with my own python games with pygame that I have tried creating and the games on that work fine with no importing errors what so ever.

I have already tried looking into the pygame's `__init__.py` code where the error is coming from and the code where all the errors are coming up looks something like this:

The code in the pygame's `__init__.py` has some imports where I think the error is coming from:

```
from pygame.base import *
from pygame.constants import *
from pygame.version import *
from pygame.rect import Rect
from pygame.compat import geterror, PY_MAJOR_VERSION
from pygame.rwobject import encode_string, encode_file_path
import pygame.surflock
import pygame.color
Color = color.Color
import pygame.bufferproxy
BufferProxy = bufferproxy.BufferProxy
import pygame.math
```

The actual output from when I run the code either on my robot or via visual studio code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robot/drive/main.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "/home/robot/drive/pygame/__init__.py", line 136, in <module>
ImportError: no module named 'pygame.base'
```

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooqsq.png)

Comment: if you put `pygame` to your own folder `/home/robot/drive` then you may have to add `/home/robot/drive` to `sys.path` before you import `pygame`.

Answer (score 0):

Python has list `sys.path` with folders in which it looks for modules. There is folder `site-packages` so `import` can find `pygame` in `site-packages/pygame` and `pygame.base` in `site-packages/pygame/base`

If you moved `pygame` to folder `/home/robot/drive` then you have to add it to `sys.path` before import

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/robot/drive/')
import pygame
```

and then it can find `pygame` in `/home/robot/drive/pygame` and `pygame.base` in `/home/robot/drive/pygame/base`

---

Normally Python looks for modules in folder in which you run code so `import pygame` can find `/home/robot/drive/pygame` without adding folder to `sys.path` but `__init__.py` runs in folder `/home/robot/drive/pygame` so `from pygame.base import *` will look for `/home/robot/drive/pygame/pygame/base` and there is to many `pygame` in path. If it would use relative path `from .base import *` then it would search in `/home/robot/drive/pygame/./base` which means `/home/robot/drive/pygame/base` so it would use correct path and it would work without adding folder to `sys.path`

Comment: I have tried adding the code you showed above to my code and it is still giving off the error.

Comment: I mean I could try adding the **WHOLE** of site-packages into the robot but I think what happened when I tried doing that was that the robot got quite confused. Also it takes a long time downloading it to the robot doing that

Comment: The folders in pygame don't exactly like what you mentioned. They aren't like `/home/robot/drive/pygame/pygame/base`. They are more like this (click on **the picture**)

Comment: there is no sense to add whole folder because it will not change problem - wrong path when it import `pygame.base`. If it runs `import pygame.base` in file which is in folder `/home/robot/drive/pygame` then /home/robot/drive/pygame + pygame.base` gives path `/home/robot/drive/pygame/pygame/base` which is wrong path. If you add `/home/robot/drive/` (without "pygame") to `sys.path` then it will try to find `/home/robot/drive/ + pygame.base` which gives `/home/robot/drive/pygame/base` and it should works.

Comment: But thats weird though I have copied your code **EXACTLY** like how you have done it but it is still giving off the same old error

Comment: I know what you mean, but it still appears to not be working

Comment: might it possibly be because I am adding a program onto an Lego ev3 robot which nobody has tried doing before.

Comment: One thing that is slightly confusing me is that you have mentioned that `/home/robot/drive/pygame/pygame/base` is the correct path in the answer. and in the comment you have put `/home/robot/drive/pygame/pygame/base` is the wrong path in the comment. Is `/home/robot/drive/pygame/pygame/base` the correct or incorrect path?

Comment: in both places I sad that `pygame/pygame` in path is wrong.

Comment: I made test and I get this error only if I use PyGame created for one Python (ie. Python 3.7) with another Python (ie. Python 3.6). Every Python has own folder for modules. Module created for one Python  may not work with other  Python - especially if module uses code in C/C++ - and PyGame uses C/C++ library [SDL 1.2](https://www.libsdl.org/). Maybe you have two Pythons and you copied PyGame from one version and use it with different version.

Comment: I am quite sure that my python on my PC is python 3.7 (the newest version I think). I think the version of python on my Lego brick is python 3.5. Do you know how I might be able to install pygame for the python3.5 version

Comment: or possibly how to install upgrade the python on the ev3dev from 3.5 to 3.7.4 (which is the one on my PC)

Comment: in Python there is no update /upgrade - you can use at the same time 3.5 and 3.7.4. If you have 3.7.4 then use `pip3.7 install pygame`  (or `python3.7 -m pip install pygame`) to install PyGame for 3.7.4 and don't copy from 3.5. Or use 3.5 instead of 3.7.4 on PC.

Comment: would I use `pip3.5 install pygame` on my robots terminal.